# Input value undefined inside nested loop - jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, input, nested, undefined

I have been trying to solve this for a while. I am trying to get value of a form input which is inside a nested loop. But its coming undefined. Any idea why so? Thanks much for your help in advance. Here is the code for example.

I am getting the value of `$(#fund-no-"+f).attr('value')` without any problem. Its `$("#year-" + year_amt + "-" + f).attr('value')` that i cant retrieve. It comes undefined. If i use `$("#year-" + year_amt + "-" + f).val()` instead i dont get any value at all.

```
 var fund_datastring;
 fund_datastring = "";
 if(fundqty >0)
 { 
  for(var f =1; f <= fundqty; f++)
  {
   fund_datastring += "&fund_no_" + f + "=" + $("#fund-no-" + f).attr('value') ;  

     var fundyear_datastring = "";
     var hidden_fundid = $("#hidden-fund-id-"+f).attr('value');

   var year_amt=2;
   //for(var year_amt =2; year_amt < hidden_fundid; year_amt++)
   while (year_amt < hidden_fundid)
   {
    fundyear_datastring += "&hidden_fund_"+f+ "=" + hidden_fundid + "&fund_"+ f +"_amount_"+ year_amt + "=" + $("#year-" + year_amt + "-" + f).attr('value') + "&fund_"+ f +"_year_"+ year_amt + "=" + year_amt;

   year_amt++
   }
   hidden_fundid = "";


  }


 }


<div class="fsFieldHorizontal"> 
    <input type="text" value="" class="fsField" size="32" name="year_1_1" id="year-1-1"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="4" id="hidden-fund-id-1"> 
        <a onclick="addFundForm(this); return false;" id="add-year-1" href="#"> 
            <img alt="Add Year" src="images/add_16.png"> 
        </a><br><br> 
        <div id="year-container-1"> 
            <div id="year-2-1" style="margin: 5px 0px;">
                <input type="text" value="" class="fsField" size="32" name="year_2_1" id="year-2-1">
                    <a onclick="removeFundYear("#year-2-1"); return false;" href="#">
                        <img alt="Remove Year 2" src="images/cancel_16.png">
                    </a><br>
                    <label for="year-2-1" class="fsSupporting">Year 2 Amount</label>
            </div>
            <div id="year-3-1" style="margin: 5px 0px;">
                <input type="text" value="" class="fsField" size="32" name="year_3_1" id="year-3-1">
                    <a onclick="removeFundYear("#year-3-1"); return false;" href="#">
                        <img alt="Remove Year 3" src="images/cancel_16.png">
                    </a><br>
                    <label for="year-3-1" class="fsSupporting">Year 3 Amount</label>
            </div>
        </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: yeah. thanks. that was my typo. I meant .val(). But how come even .val() not returning any value when i replaced .attr('value'). I checked it in Firebug.

Comment: Are you sure your selector actually matches elements from the DOM? Could you please try to do `alert($("#year-" + year_amt + "-" + f).length)` ?

Comment: Yes i do have the element matching. Here is the HTML from Firebug. See Below.

Comment: @Abu - Indenting code greatly increases readability. - I indented the HTML for you. It's much easier to pick out the IDs like this.

Comment: @Abu: Related to Peter's point, there are a **lot** of IDs in that code. I'd probably look to do more of this with structure and relative traversal rather than using specific IDs all over the place. For instance, those links that delete the year's div could all use a single `click` handler: `$(this).parent('div').remove()` (or `removeFundYear($(this).parent('div'))` if you need to do something other than just remove the element). I used to use IDs for everything and found that it just causes these kinds of problems; relative traversal worked wonders for my code clarity. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks T.J for the tips. Am Relatively new to jQuery. Very interesting. Will certainly try to implement your idea.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tried to look for autoindent or html tags. The code was not indented as i copied from the firebug edit console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2**

As I suspected below, your IDs were not unique: You have both this:

```
<div id="year-2-1" style="margin: 5px 0px;">
```

And this:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="fsField" size="32" name="year_2_1" id="year-2-1">
```

jQuery is probably finding the first one, which does not (of course) have a `value`.

**Update 1**

From what you're describing, the most likely scenario is that you don't have an element with the ID `year-2-1` (on the first pass) and so on — or you have more than one such element (which is invalid and so unpredictable). Because fundamentally, if the DOM is right, it works: http://jsbin.com/icume3 And if there's no element with that ID, you get exactly what you're describing: http://jsbin.com/icume3/2

**Old, apparently incorrect answer** *(in more ways than one)*:

You haven't shown your markup, but my guess would be that [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is working where `.attr("value")` is not because you're dealing with a form element that doesn't have a `value` attribute, <s>like a `select`</s> *(see below)*. [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) gets the value of the element, which varies depending on what kind of element it is.

*Edit*: Apparently jQuery handles "value" in `attr`, at least for `select`s, at least on the browsers I tried (including IE6, so): http://jsbin.com/oxega3 So not that.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing it inside a jQuery funciton. Its my mistake. I meant .val(). I dont get any value even with $("#year-" + year_amt + "-" + f).val(). I checked it in Firebug where there is no value recorded.

Comment: @Abu: I misread the `val` part of your question originally, sorry. Updated.

Comment: If there are multiple elements with the same id (which is bad practice) jQuery just return the first one, unless you do `$('[id=myId]')` which fulls it, but looses the performance gain of the native implementation.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am using unique IDs for sure. As i am creating using loops so each have a different ID. I attached the HTML that was seen in the Firebug window.

Comment: @Dan: If jQuery's Sizzle engine is deferring to `document.getElementById` in the simple ID selector case (and I believe it is), you **cannot** rely on it matching the first such element in the tree. The behavior can vary amongst implementations. Some implementations may return the last, rather than the first, for instance.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: True, it uses the native implementation of the browser, but so far I haven't seen a browser that behaves differently ... although there might be

Comment: @Abu - DIV with ID `year-2-1` is on line 8 **and** 9 of the HTML. It's not unique. ==> `<div id="year-2-1" style="margin: 5px 0px;"><input type="text" value="" class="fsField" size="32" name="year_2_1" id="year-2-1">`

Comment: @Abu: You have a `div` and an `input` with the same ID. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks T.J. I havent seen that out of so many ids...let me try it after i change.

Comment: Huge Thanks to T.J. Great response. I didn't even think of checking the Div ids. I changed teh Div id's to "divyear-#-#" and it works great. I was more looking into the source instead of the HTML code which is why the error escaped. Will be more careful in the future. Thanks a lot everyone for your answers. Great Site!

Comment: @Abu: Good deal, glad that helped! Yeah, it's a good place -- stick around, answer a few questions (but try not to get addicted and neglect your *own* work -- it's been known to happen). :-)